# How to convert xml to sqlite?

Tags: iphone, xml, sqlite

I have an xml file that has a lot of info that I would like it to be in sqlite tables.

I am wondering if there's any tool, app to transform xml to sqlite.

By the way I am on OS X and I need the info for an iPhone app, so I can also take scripts or some source code to make the trasmformation.

Answer (score 4):

Use XSLT to transform the XML into insert statements.

Answer (score 4):

The SQLite Manager firefox plugin has an XML importer : 
http://code.google.com/p/sqlite-manager/

The XML import / Export is described here :

http://code.google.com/p/sqlite-manager/wiki/FAQ#XML_import_and_export

Comment: thx. I already solve this. I couldn't import the xml to the SQLite Manager instead of that I exported the xml as a cvs file and then imported the cvs file to the SQLite Manager... worked as a charm!

Comment: That extension is dead - there's a new same-named ext listed for FF but it has a different dev (Luna) and has no import feature, sadly.